# How to handle pjsip message?

Tags: pjsip, pjsua2

I received some message like this:

```
07:27:06.671           pjsua_core.c  .RX 544 bytes Request msg MESSAGE/cseq=20 (rdata0x7ff3a00086b8) from UDP 192.168.42.128:5060:
MESSAGE sip:34020000002000000001@3402000000 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.42.128:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK40553892
From: <sip:34020000001320000001@3402000000>;tag=365877371
To: <sip:34020000002000000001@3402000000>
Call-ID: 300721342
CSeq: 20 MESSAGE
Content-Type: Application/MANSCDP+xml
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: IP Camera
Content-Length:   179

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="GB2312"?>
<Notify>
<CmdType>Keepalive</CmdType>
<SN>2608</SN>
<DeviceID>34020000001320000001</DeviceID>
<Status>OK</Status>
<Info>
</Info>
</Notify>
```

I use `on_rx_request()` listen it, and just print something.

```
static pj_bool_t default_mod_on_rx_request(pjsip_rx_data *rdata) {

    cout << "=================== rx request ======================\n\n\n" << endl;

    pjsip_endpt_create_response(pjsua_get_pjsip_endpt(), rdata, 200, NULL, &tdata);
    pjsip_endpt_send_response2(pjsua_get_pjsip_endpt(), rdata, tdata, NULL, NULL);
    return PJ_TRUE;
}
```

use pjsip_module and register it, `REGISTER` req is ok!

```
pjsip_endpt_register_module(pjsua_get_pjsip_endpt(), &mod_default_handler);
```

when running, there is not thing output, so how should I handle data. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know, `MESSAGE` should handle with Account's `onInstantMessage()` method in pjsua2. eg:

```
void ServerAccount::onInstantMessage(OnInstantMessageParam &prm)
{
  std::cout << "prm.fromUri: " + prm.fromUri << std::endl;
  std::cout << "prm.toUri: " + prm.toUri << std::endl;
  std::cout << "prm.contactUri: " + prm.contactUri << std::endl;
  std::cout << "prm.contentType: " + prm.contentType << std::endl;

  std::cout << "---------" << std::endl;
  std::cout << prm.msgBody << std::endl;
}
```

Params Document: [OnInstantMessageParam](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpj_1_1OnInstantMessageParam.htm)